# Why doesn't the latest version of angular support global controller functions?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

With the AngularJs new version 1.3.0 don't but with 1.2.9 the old version work. Whats the new in the new version ?

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller = "MyController">
            <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
            <p>{{ author.title }}</p>
        </div>

        <script>

            function MyController($scope) {
                $scope.author = {
                    'name': 'Nagy Dávid',
                    'title': 'Demo',
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why this question got so many close votes. I thought it was a good question.

Comment: @pixelbits Well, it certainly is not a _good_ question, but it could be acceptable. However, I guess people are unhappy because not all required information is given - To which exact version does the "old" and "new" version refer to? Also, I guess the rather poor English is a contributing factor.

Comment: @user3140323 please add specifics around old and new version.

Comment: Sorry Old version 1.2.9 New version 1.3.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a breaking change in angular *v1.3.0-beta.15*, so that, by default, angular will no longer look for controllers on window. See [3f2232b5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018) for more details.

```
With the exception of simple demos, it is not helpful to use globals
for controller constructors. This adds a new method to `$controllerProvider`
to re-enable the old behavior, but disables this feature by default.

BREAKING CHANGE:
`$controller` will no longer look for controllers on `window`.
The old behavior of looking on `window` for controllers was originally intended
for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller
functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by
default.

To migrate, register your controllers with modules rather than exposing them
as globals:
```

Therefore, to make your example work without creating your own module (not recommend though), you could add this code in the script tag at the bottom:

```
angular.module('ng').config(function ($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
});
```

For a working example, see a plunker below.

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xdlfJRpH8lHzNvqyQ0no?p=preview

Comment: How to make my example with this $controllerProvider ? Please Help!