# Getting Started With AngularJS Plunk Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, plunker

I am new to Angular JS. I am trying to start with the basic Hello World Program. Here is my plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/uW1fHB7a17gpvn341sn3?p=preview.

```js
var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I created a simple controller and has a single model binding in that. It is not working for me. I am not able to get what the problem is. Can anybody please help me in getting started.

Comment: You changed the plunk since the answers appeared - the plunk no longer reflects the question when you asked it :(

Comment: I had already marked the correct answer given by @scniro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boostrap your app properly and define your controller correctly. Observe the following changes...

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

---

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', MainController)
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9M42IO2bvmyFiSe6GYT?p=preview) - updated demo

The AngularJS [Getting Started](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started) resources should be packed with everything you'd like to know to get up and running

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. It was working fine with AngularJS 1.2.1, however it was not working with 1.4.5. So is this updated way to get started?

Comment: The plunker works fine with 1.4.5, did you check it out? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No, the code you had written is working fine for me. I am just asking the code that was written by me was working fine for AngularJS 1.2.1 but not for version 1.4.5

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you are saying now. It was working because AngularJS suported global controller use in earlier versions, which has now been removed. See SO [Why doesn't the latest version of angular support global controller functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112978/why-doesnt-the-latest-version-of-angular-support-global-controller-functions) for some more details on that topic. So yes, this is considered the "updated" way to get started

Comment: Thanks a lot @scniro. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.

You need to create an angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

The second argument is an array of dependency modules.  You don't need one here.

Then change `ng-app` to `ng-app="myApp"` referencing whatever you named your module.

Then you need to create a controller the angular way.

```
app.controller('MainController',MainController);
```

Here's the full script. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/llXWoQvqi5Dbyke82aYu?p=preview)

```
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello World';
}

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('MainController',MainController);
```

Comment: it is similar, though definitely not copied from yours :) And written at the same time.

Comment: @bluetoft Thanks for the quick solution. It was working fine with AngularJS 1.2.1, however it was not working with 1.4.5. So is this updated way to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code works fine with Angular 1.0, just not with 1.4
Just thought it was worth mentioning, in case you were following a tutorial, and wondering why it wasn't working or something.

See this plunkr working fine in 1.0 with equivalent code to yours...
http://plnkr.co/edit/zbWvwxVDvhhVKgc5lGrr?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      {{message}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, Angular!";
}
```