# Why is my AngularJS controller definition and markup not working as expected? - <controller> is not a function error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Marks</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="subject in student.subjects">
            <td> {{ subject.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ subject.marks }} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have the following script:

```
function studentController($scope) {
        $scope.student = {
            subjects:[
                {name:'Physics',marks:70},
                {name:'Chemistry',marks:80},
                {name:'Math',marks:65},
                {name:'English',marks:75},
                {name:'Hindi',marks:67}
            ]
        };
    }
```

In the console the error says that the `studentController` is not a function. So it could be from the JS but I dont notice anything, ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/28728380/2435473

Comment: Maybe it is the missing app here: ng-app=""

Comment: you didnt define the controller as a module controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Global controllers are no longer supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018); you must define them properly. See SO question: [Why doesn't the latest version of angular support global controller functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112978/why-doesnt-the-latest-version-of-angular-support-global-controller-functions) for some details on this - since you'll still find orphaned tutorials out there using this old pattern. Observe the following...

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
    /*...*/
});
```

---

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="studentController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Marks</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="subject in student.subjects">
            <td> {{ subject.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ subject.marks }} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cxavg7fa/) - working demo

Comment: You are correct sir. Looks like the tutorial I am using is from early 2014. Thank you!

Comment: @FroyT great! Please remember to accept answer if you found helpful and enjoy all the great learning ahead of you :)